# allowedContentTypes in fluidcontent for fluid_styled_content

Tags: typo3, fluid

For my templating i am using the fluid powered TYPO3 extension (flux, vhs, fluidpages, fluidcontent).
For the default Templates im am using fluid_styled_content.

I can restrict the content types with the following markup:

```
<flux:grid.column colPos="2" name="hero" label="Hero Image">
    <flux:form.variable name="allowedContentTypes" value="fluidcontent_content" />
    <flux:form.variable name="Fluidcontent" value="{allowedContentTypes: 'Vendor.ExtensionName:HeroImage.html'}" />
</flux:grid.column>
```

But now i want to restrict to only allow a fluid_styled_content element.
I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
<flux:grid.column colPos="1" variables="{allowedContentTypes: 'text,textpic'}" />
```

Is it because i use fluid_styled_content and not css_styled_content?

My Setup:
TYPO3 7.6.2
flux: 7.3.0
fluidcontent: 4.4.0
fluidpages: 3.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fluid_styled_content there is no longer a `text` or `textpic` CType. It is called `textmedia` now. So try:

```
<flux:grid.column colPos="1" variables="{allowedContentTypes: 'textmedia'}" />
```

Comment: Is it always the lowercase Template File name? Why is the naming convention different in fluid content?